# Send a variable to a processes using PID in command line?

Tags: php, shell, command-line, cmd, pid

I have a processes that is open and can retrieve variables but it is running in the back ground.

so i need to send a variable to the processes using the PID ?? is it possible in the command line to send a variable to a processes or to reconnect to a processes.

Comment: you can try running as a `service` and build a way to interact with it.

Comment: Is there any reason this is tagged php/shell/command-line/cmd/pid?
Most shell commands are specific to the terminal you are using. PHP is executed in an interpreter and is shell-independent. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

***nix type shells**

You can reconnect to a process by doing `fg [job id]` (which isn't the PID but you can find it by using the `jobs` command from terminal)

**IPC**

You can also send variables into programs if the program is configured to accept it. It may read it off of a pipe, file, or network socket

A program is also able to receive signals (sent with the `kill -[signal]`) if its simply waiting for a boolean message

For php, sending variables through these methods may involve [serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) of the variables prior to transmission

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. is the fg[job id ] can connect to the processes but not by the PID, then how ??

Comment: assuming you are in a terminal, if you type `jobs` it will give you an output listing the running programs (spawned in from that session) and their 'job id'. If you type `fg jobid` then it will bring it back to the foreground where you can interact with it

Comment: when i type jobs i don't get anything in return

Comment: how did you background your program?

Comment: It should be something like `$ ./program&` or using the `Ctrl-Z` escape and then `bg`. When you background it using either of these, it also tells you the job id

Comment: well i didnt background my program i run it through php exec() function so it is running in the background as far as i know

Comment: So how is the program receiving the variable? is it interactive? does using a pipe (similar to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#107456) work? How about using PHP expect (http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.expect.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Interprocess communication is often handled by sockets, which are [supported in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).  So if you have control over both applications you can set up sockets to communicate between them.

Comment: I researched about sockets before but i cant find anything about how to connect and reconnect using PID. it is a little not understandable, do you have any simpler tutorial different than the normal one you can find on google when you search for socket

Comment: Sockets are not connected by PID. Most commonly, the program will be configured to listen on an IP/port (can be localhost). Alternatively, on POSIX systems you can use `socketpair` in conjunction with `sendmsg` and `recvmsg`.  In PHP this is implemented with socket_create_pair (http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-pair.php)